# GWT: is properties global for whole application?

Tags: gwt, properties

I've got the following config `<when-property-is name="isExecute" value="true" />`.

1. Am I able to set property `isExecute` for module A `true` and for module B `false`?
2. Am I able to change property value by Java?
3. Does `GWT.create` read property condition each call or only once (cache)?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? Replacing implementations during runtime? You can use Generator to do this.